# htaccess redirect and not change the url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, yeoman

How could i change page url without redirecting?

File structure:

```
/www
/www/app
/www/app/index.html
/www/app/.htaccess
```

.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(demo1|demo2)\/?$ app [L]
```

**For example**

```
domain.dev/app (index.html page)
domain.dev/app/demo1 (here i want to open my /index.html page without changing url to it)
domain.dev/app/demo2 (same as demo1 route)
```

Comment: Change your RewriteRule to: `RewriteRule ^(demo1|demo2)\/?$ app/$1 [L]`

Comment: What URL do you want to see in browser?